# ERROR | No such comm target registered: jupyter.widget.control

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am just getting started with tech, and I installed Jupyter Notebook on my laptop but upon running it encountered the following error messages:

```
***C:\Users\mugan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\nbformat\__init__.py:128: MissingIDFieldWarning: Code cell is missing an id field, this will become a hard error in future nbformat versions. You may want to use `normalize()` on your notebooks before validations (available since nbformat 5.1.4). Previous versions of nbformat are fixing this issue transparently, and will stop doing so in the future.
  validate(nb)
C:\Users\mugan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py:353: MissingIDFieldWarning: Code cell is missing an id field, this will become a hard error in future nbformat versions. You may want to use `normalize()` on your notebooks before validations (available since nbformat 5.1.4). Previous versions of nbformat are fixing this issue transparently, and will stop doing so in the future.
  validate_nb(model['content'])***
```

I have tried to resolve using:

```
***$jupyter notebook --generate-config***
```

Comment: If you are just getting started, you'll have an easier time using [the Anaconda distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution) on your machine.